# smbclient works in interactive shell but not in the browser (selinux)

Tags: php, centos, smb, selinux, libsmbclient

I have a very simple page attempting to shell_exec to initiate a smbclient.

The line works fine in interactive shell, but fails in the browser.

**Interactive Shell**

```
[root@vle html]# php -a
Interactive shell

php > $exec = exec("smbclient //*IP*/*Share* -U *Username*%*Password*");
Domain=[...] OS=[Windows Server 2012 Standard 9200] Server=[Windows Server 2012 Standard 6.2]
```

This works as intended. However, when doing it in a PHP file, powered by Apache I get this:

**Test PHP File executed in browser**

```
<?php
$exec = exec("smbclient //*IP*/*Share* -U *Username*%*Password");
print_r($exec);
// returns Connection to *IP* failed (Error NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED)
?>
```

When attempting to use libsmbclient for php I get the following error:

> Warning: Couldn't open SMB directory smb://*IP*/*Share*: unknown error
>   (110)

Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing it to work in interactive shell but not in the browser?

Server is CentOS 6

**UPDATE**

I've narrowed the issue down to being caused by SELinux (I temporarily disabled it).

Does anyone know how to permit smbclient through selinux?

Comment: it sounds like permissions issues...

Comment: are you running apache on linux or windows ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Edited to include question and server (Centos). I've gave the file 777 to check permissions and it isn't working

Comment: Discovered the problem is caused by selinux

Comment: @ThomasLomas was was the workaround for Selinux?